# Scrapy nested selectors with conditions

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to run the following code on the node that can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/r0GaCVLh

Basically: if my node is a `table fielded` I want to do a specific processing on the table otherwise if it is a `table substitutes` I want a different one.

For a reason completely beyond me the conditions:

```
if table.xpath('./*[@class="table fielded"]'):
```

and

```
if table.xpath('./*[@class="table substitutes"]'):
```

seem to fail. And the variable `fielded` is never set.
Here is the snippet of the code that doesn't work (the `print` are only there for debut purposes):

```
for table in sel.xpath('.//table[@class="table fielded" or @class="table substitutes"]'):
  print table.extract()
  if table.xpath('./*[@class="table fielded"]'):
    fielded = True
    print fielded
  if table.xpath('./*[@class="table substitutes"]'):
    fielded = False
    print fielded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at this line:

```
if table.xpath('./*[@class="table fielded"]')
```

Here you are searching for any element that has a `table fielded` class *inside the already found `table`*. Obviously, there are no elements matching this locator.

Instead, extract the `@class` value and make a decision based on it's value:

```
for table in sel.xpath('.//table[@class="table fielded" or @class="table substitutes"]'):
    table_class = table.xpath("@class").extract_first()

    if "fielded" in table_class:
        # do smth
```

Comment: when printing the already found table i do see that the first node is called `<table class="table fielded">` or `<table class="table substitutes">` which is what confuses me. In your answer don't you rely on that too? I mean `table_class = table.xpath("@class").extract_first()` with extract `fielded`or not because the first class is `<table class="table fielded">` or `<table class="table substitutes">`?
Apart from that let me try your answer :)

Comment: @vrleboss yeah, sorry, I was not probably clear. Inside the loop, you already have a `table` and if you would call `xpath()` on it, it is going down the tree not including the `table` itself. In other words, `table` element is the current context and if you want to access it's attributes, do it directly with `@attribute` like in the provided answer..hope it's a bit clearer. Thanks.

Comment: It works great @alexce. To understand completely scrapy behavior: does it omit the first node of "the already found table" as you call it? Then why can I still look at the class name of that "already found table"